# Connect phone to tv usb

Tags: usb, connection-issues, lg-g2, smart-tv

I have plugged my phone up to my through the usb and on my phone it says connected as media device. But when I go to the usb in the settings on my tv it says there no device connected. Any ideas?

Comment: Yupp. Your TV probably doesn't support MTP – and recent Android versions no longer support USB mass storage. Both speak a "different language", so to say, and cannot understand each other.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways:

- Some smartphones support MHL (Mobile HDMI Link) cables.
- Most smartphones are equipped with Miracast. Screen Mirroring can be enabled/disabled in the quick toggle menu, which also contains WiFi,Bluetooth,Torch,etc.

Answer (score 0):

The phone is just charging and not connected because maybe your TV doesn't support that feature.
Try using Screen Mirroring in Settings>Display>Wireless Display.